# Buffer a stream piped to res in node.js/express

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a command I'm running for video streaming via ffmpeg, that basically pipes the response to `res` within express.

For example:

```
var args = ['-re','-i','/video.mkv','-loglevel','quiet','-r',24,'-threads',7,'-b:v','512k','-b:a','96k','-c:v','libx264','-c:a','libfdk_aac','-ar',22050,'-f','flv','pipe:1']
  , command = spawn('ffmpeg', args);

command.stdout.pipe(res);
```

What I'd like to do is "buffer" this for a few seconds before the output is piped to res.  I've tried creating a `new stream.Writeable()`, which takes in the `stdout`, then using a `setTimeout` for 3 seconds, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are node `>=0.10` you can just do

```
var args = ['-re','-i','/video.mkv','-loglevel','quiet','-r',24,'-threads',7,'-b:v','512k','-b:a','96k','-c:v','libx264','-c:a','libfdk_aac','-ar',22050,'-f','flv','pipe:1']
    , command = spawn('ffmpeg', args);

setTimeout(function(){
    command.stdout.pipe(res);
}, 3000);
```

Streams buffer by default, so you just wait to pipe it until later.